# Finish transition effect

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8, expression-blend

I have a menu that shows up and hides with transition effects:

[image: Open]

[image: Closed]

The elements you see are navigating you to other pages.

So when i navigate to other page i do:

```
MenuButton.Tag = "MenuDisabled";
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "HideMenu", true);
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AboutPageAuthorized.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

But it happens that navigation is working faster than effect, so you will see it sliding till the middle and then fast dissapear - its annoying.

**Is there a way to handle this effect breaking thing?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a delay before you call the navigation, you can add the delay [using System.Timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx)
Just add the navigation event under OnTimedEvent, and adjust the timer according to your needs.

```
//Place the effect here

// Create a timer with a ten second interval.
aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

// Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

// Set the Interval to 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds).
aTimer.Interval = 2000;
aTimer.Enabled = true;

private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AboutPageAuthorized.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```